# Problem updating multi-row

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

table:`ProductComapny`

field:`NameProduct`

NameProduct

1

1

1

4

5

i want update fields NameProduct where NameProduct= `1` to(NameProduct=`1`,NameProduct=`2`,NameProduct=`3`

how can this work??

result

NameProduct

1

2

3

4

5

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
var source = new int[] {1,1,1,4,5};
var result = source.Select( (val,i) => val==1 ? i : val );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext dc=new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var my = from a in dc.ProductComapny
                 where a.NameProduct== 1
                 select a;

        int i=1;
        foreach (var item in my)
        {
            item.NameProduct= i;
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            i++;
        }
    }
```